# Sometimes I get null output without stderr when using FFMPEG to cut mp4

Tags: ffmpeg

Linux system，The ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -ss 1260.349 -i http://example.com/xxx.mp4 -t 19.000 -y out.mp4
```

If I run the command again, it works with correct output.

The wrong output info:
[output info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqJGw.png)

Does anyone know why？Thanks.

Comment: Does it happen with a local file?

Comment: No, it just happens when using url as an input.

Comment: Then, unreliable network or network stack.

Comment: If it caused by the unreliable network or network stack, wouldn't it cause a StdErr? I exec the command with GO language, and when the problem showed up, I didn't get any stdErr. The code is just like this: 
```
execCmd := exec.Command("ffmpeg", paramList...)
go func(execCmd *exec.Cmd) {
out, err := execCmd.CombinedOutput()
if err != nil {
    logs.Warn("ffmpeg exec failed. ", cmd)
}}(execCmd)
select {...}
```
I didn't see the warn print in my log when it happened.